# Good use cases for the calc() function in CSS?

Tags: html, css, calc

I have been playing around a bit with the `calc()` function in `CSS`. Mixing percentages and absolute values and sizing units is very helpful. But I have not found a lot of use cases except for some layout calculations.

It has a good browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

So back to my question, have you found any good examples or use cases of this `CSS` function?

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your div in center of body

```
<style>
body{
position:relative;
}
.message{
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
left:calc(50% - 50px);
}
</style>


<div class="message">Message</div>
```

its set completely center in all devices.

Comment: But this is just another layout calculation that the OP said he already was aware of. Anyway, this is not good coding practice, since the `50px` is dependent on the `100px`, and changing the size will require changes in two places. There are better ways to center things.

Comment: @user663031 that problem can be solved now with css variables